# Alternate way to use page method inside user control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, pagemethods

Is there a way by which i can achieve functionality of page method inside a user control.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is probably to put the functionality you want in a webservice then use the [scriptservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute to make that available.

Works very similarly to a page method.

Quite an extensive example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx).

```
        <asp:ScriptManager>
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MyWs.asmx" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then you can call your webmethods in JS: MyNamespace.MyWs.MyMethod();

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to put my WebMethods in a custom class that is derived from System.Web.UI.Page

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool MyMethod(string value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then whenever I have a page containing a usercontrol that needs to consume that WebMethod, I derive that page from my custom page class instead of System.Web.UI.Page.