# PageMethods is not defined

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, master-pages, pagemethods

I am setting up PageMethods to access server side code using javascript. I am receiving the error "PageMethods is not defined" when i debug using firebug. the server side code is not being fired as well.

I have setup my script manager "EnablePageMethods" to true. My method is public & static and it has the WebMethod attribute set up as well. Still i m receiving the above error. Can it be because of the script manager being in a top level master page which has two child master pages and then my page is called:

i.e.

Main Master Page (with script manager) -> Primary master page -> Secondary master page -> My page -> My User control (having the WebMethod)

Is it possible tht the hierarchy is causing this issue?

This is the webmethod

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void AddNote(string t)
{
    int propid = 1; 
    if (propid > 0)
    {
     //Call my method
    }
}
```

this is my javascript code:

```
  function editNodes(t) {
    alert('test1');
    alert(t);
    PageMethods.AddNote(t,OnSuccess,OnFailure);
    alert('method called');
}
function OnSuccess() { 
    alert('Success'); 
    if (!navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }

}
function OnFailure(error) {
    alert('Error:' + error);
}
```

this is where I am calling it:

```
   <a href="#" class="btngeneral" onclick="javascript:editNodes(2);">Save</a>
```

Comment: Can you please paste here the code that you use tho access the page method on the client?

Comment: Make sure the script manager tag is in the top level page, in your case the master page.

Answer (score 16):

Page Methods don't work in either Master Pages or User Controls.

If you move the method up one level to you page it should work.

Never really been able to get a definitive answer on this one.

I suspect it has do with the fact that aspx pages inherit from the Page class and the ascx controls inherit from the UserControl class. As to why of that I am not too sure.

Personally I would use a generic handler (.ashx) page and call that through javascript.

Comment: This is really, and only one, useful comment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

set EnablePageMethods="true"

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager" 
                               runat="server" 
                               AsyncPostBackTimeout="99999999"
                               EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

i hope this will work for you

Comment: This was the solution for me! In my case, it was a Telerik RadScriptManager that I had to set EnablePageMethods="true".

Comment: Kinda old post, but wanted to comment anyways. I enabled `EnablePageMethods="true"` in my `<asp:ScriptManager...` code on my master page and worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, PageMethods on usercontrol is not supported and threads below seem to confirm that

http://forums.asp.net/p/977525/1242935.aspx

[ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods from UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249304/asp-net-ajax-page-methods-from-usercontrol)

But I think there could be a workaround (not sure if that's efficient in your scenario). You can write a OneLine PageMethod in page's code behind which would intern call the Controls Page method. Now you can invoke your page's method from aspx and all set to go.

Or you may use ths alternative
[Alternate way to use page method inside user control asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229621/alternate-way-to-use-page-method-inside-user-control-asp-net)