# How can i get page method object value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below page method in my aspx page. Page method returns more than 1000 lines. But in success result alert return only "[object][Object]" string. How can i get the return string.

```
 function getName()
 {
    PageMethods.getAdCodeInfo(onSuccess(),onError());
 }

 function onSuccess(result)
 {
    alert(result);//Result Returns more than 1000 lines string
 }

 function onError(error)
 {
    alert("error "+error);
 }
```

Comment: Tried `result.responseText`?

Comment: Did you add `ScriptManager` and `EnablePagemthods` property to true

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818265/pagemethods-is-not-defined

Comment: success message return less than 1060 lines

Comment: If i line exceed the length 1065 means it returns error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function onSuccess(result)
 {
    if(result && result.length>0){
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
             alert(result[i].prop); // prop is the property what you want to alert.
        }
    }
 }
```