# Call JavaScript from codebehind and inside the script call function in codebehind (PageMethods is undefind)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I need to call confirmation message box from codebehind as the user select data from `dropdown` list and when the selected data is 1 for example a confirmation box will appear to the user to confirm his action 
so I did that as below in the code behind I called this JavaScript method:

```
if (dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CallConfirmBox", "CallConfirmBox();", true);
}
```

The script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallConfirmBox() {
    if (confirm("هل تريد ان تفصل الباليت؟")) {
                   alert("سيتم فصل الباليت!");
        PageMethods.getdata(onSuccess, onError); 
        function onSuccess() {
            alert(data);
        }

        function onError() {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }            
         }
    } else {
        //CANCEL – Do your stuff or call any callback method here..
        alert("done!");
    }
}
```

And I've added the below line at the beginning of the HTML code:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

and Here is the code behind function that is called from script :

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public static void getdata()
    {

        int nRowsCheck = cMDP.Update_Segregation_PalletPart(nPalletNo);
        if (nRowsCheck != 0)
        {
            nRowsCheck = 0;
            nRowsCheck = cMDP.Update_Segregation_Pallet(nPalletNo, nUserID);
            if (nRowsCheck != 0)
            {
                nRowsCheck = 0;

                nRowsCheck = cMDP.Delete_Segregation_PalletPart_Delete(nPalletNo);
                if (nRowsCheck != 0)
                {
                    nRowsCheck = 0;
                    nRowsCheck = cMDP.Delete_Segregation_Pallet_Delete(nPalletNo);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But I've got the below error:

> Page Methods is undefined when run the script !!

Please help as I need some support

Comment: what is `PageMethods.getdata(onSuccess, onError);`

Comment: It is the function of the codebehind as mentioned above in the code

Comment: It's working for me. Only I changed: `if (dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == "1")` and removed one `}` before the `else` in your javascript.

Comment: @krlzlx does it call getdata() in code behind ?

Comment: I changed what you have done but nothing happens same error appears :(

Comment: Yes my break-point hits the getData in code-behind. Is your WebMethod in the same page as your javascript? Are you sure you have `EnablePageMethods="true"` in your ScriptManager? I had the same error before I set this attribute. Is your ScriptManager after a `<form id="yourId" runat="server">` tag?

Comment: yes my script manager is after form tag 
the code behind function is at the same ascx page but in the code behind and script in the source html

Comment: So it seems you're using a User Control. Page Methods cannot be used in a User Control. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41857198/1351076).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to remove one `}` before the `else` in your JavaScript.

Change in your code-behind:

```
if (dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == "1")
```

For the main problem: `Page Methods is undefined`:

It seems from your comment that you're using a User Control (ascx). **Page Methods cannot be used in a User Control**. Please refer to these questions:

- [PageMethods is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5818265)
- [ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods from UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249304)

The easiest solution is to use an aspx WebForm instead of an ascx User Control. That's what I've tested and worked.

Or you can use a WebService, as specified in the following question:

- [Alternate way to use page method inside user control asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229621/alternate-way-to-use-page-method-inside-user-control-asp-net)

But the link to the sample is not working anymore.

Or you can try to use this project that tries to bring ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods to UserControls:

- [Control Methods for ASP.NET AJAX](http://controlmethods.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I've done what you have described but now it gives error that the CallConfirmBox() is undefined however I've write the script after <html> tag in the form ?

Comment: I solved the problem as I had to put the script inside the body and form tag :) 
but now I've one more question if I want to call a function that refresh the controls used in the form and a datagrid view that is bind to database inside the page methods function how to do that although it is not static and the controls are not static ?

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. You don't need to put your script after the form tag. You can put it in the `<head>` element. If you have a new question, please create a new one as it's not convenient to answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Change you javascript code:

   ```
       PageMethods.getdata(onSuccess, onError);

       function onSuccess(data)
       {
           alert(data);
       }

       function onError(data)
       {
           alert(data);
       }
   ```

And you code behind getdata method must be a public static string function:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string  getdata()
    {
        //Do some things
        return " Operations done successfully!";            
    }
```

Comment: I've changed from control to form as per advised by Krlzlx and changed the script as per your solution but now I've a new issue is that the CallConfirmBox() is undefined however I've write the script after <html> tag in the new form ? so what is the issue

Comment: Of course it is not true. Your javascript codes must be after the scriptManager. And if you have no success, Why you have checked his answer as the true answer?